# Why is int -> size_t a narrowing conversion?

Tags: c++

Consider this code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    uint16_t z{1};
    uint16_t x{2};
    size_t y{x << z};

    return (int)y;
}
```

This code produces messages on GCC, Clang, and MSVC saying that `size_t y{x << z}` is a narrowing conversion. (A warning on GCC, an error on the other two).

According to GCC's warning message, `x` and `z` are being promoted to int. OK that makes some sense.

What I don't understand is how a conversion from `int` to `size_t` is a "narrowing" conversion, since `size_t` is larger than `int`.

Interestingly, to me at least, is that if I change the definition of `x` to `uint32_t x{2}`, the code compiles without issue.

Comment: Negative numbers.

Comment: Since it's an `uint16_t` that gets converted to `int`, you can be sure that the `int` is not negative. `size_t y{static_cast<unsigned>(x) << z};` is a safe way to get rid of the warning. `uint32_t` is most probably a `typedef` for `unsigned` in your implementation.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, I knew how to get rid of the error. I was more curious about the why. Still not quite sure how negative numbers are involved, unless the resulting 32-bit `int` is first being converted to a 64-bit `long long`?

Comment: A narrowing conversion is a conversion where information can be lost. In this case the compiler's worried about losing sign information on negative numbers which are not actually possible in this case.

Comment: The promotion rules in C++ (and in C) allow for a smaller unsigned integer to be promoted to a larger signed integer.  Curly brace initialization disallows narrowing conversions, as a safety feature.  And that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 3):

Though both `int` and `size_t` may be the same bit-wdth they differ in that the `int` is a signed value, so it's range (for, e.g. 16-bit) would be [-32768..+32767] while the same hypothetical 16-bit `size_t` would be in [0..65535] range.
That conversion from a signed value to an unsigned is what is being reported as "narrowing".

A fix (in this case) is based on knowledge that your values are indeed unsigned so you can "tell" the compiler as much with an explicit conversion:

```
auto y{static_cast<size_t>(x << z)};
```

Comment: Further reading: [Formal definition of Narrowing Conversion (**dcl.init.list** /7)](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7)

Comment: Minor point: `int` has to be large enough to hold all the values in the range [-32767 .. 32767], so at least 16 bits. +1.

Comment: Actually, part of my point was that `int` and `size_t` are not the same bit-width. On the platforms I tried this on, `int` is 32 bits while `size_t` is 64 bits.